# Sharepoint Performance After Moving to Subdomain

Tags: 2016, performance

We recently moved our sharepoint 2016 site to a subdomain, basically test.com -> a.test.com, but we are now experiencing some intermittent performance issues. There doesn't seem to be a real pattern to it. Some pages will take a few minutes to load at times, but then at other times they will load in a few seconds.

Our infrastructure is a load balancer to two front ends, one app server, and a single database server which has worked fine for the last 4 years or so.

When we switched to the new subdomain we unextended the application and then reextended after making the domain name change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Well, that doesn't make any sense! I'd suggest Fiddler to begin with to see the response times of pages and API calls. SQL performance would also be beneficial to look at but I don't think that the issue would stem from there. It might also be worth bypassing a load balancer on the client and hit each FE independently to remove the LB as a possible cause.

Comment: Not sure how "recent" your change was taking, it worth reboot all your servers and network equipment in case cache issue.